# Sub query not working correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am currently creating a database and trying to use a variety of queries. I can't however seem to get my sub query to work.

The code below shows my current code I'm trying to get the customers name, address, and telephone when the customer ID is = 21345432 instead the display shows me all customers not just that specific one.

Code:

```
select Customer_Name, Customer_Address, Customer_Telephone
from CustomerInfo
where (Select CustomerID from CustomerInfo where CustomerID = "21345432");
```

Comment: Why do the select, especially if you have the customerid already?  you can just do the where customerID = "21345432". Although, you are using a string... which could potentially have spaces saved in there so maybe you need to do a like comparison?

Answer (score 2):

If you did need a sub-query it would look like this:

```
select Customer_Name, Customer_Address, Customer_Telephone
from CustomerInfo
where specialID = (Select specialID from sometable);
```

> Remember, if the sub-query gives more than one result this will give an error.  If you want more than one result then you really want a join. (or use `in` like Prdp's answer)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sub-query`

```
SELECT Customer_Name,
       Customer_Address,
       Customer_Telephone
FROM   CustomerInfo
WHERE  CustomerID = 21345432
```

Double quotes are used for identifiers.For string literals use single quotes and Integer values can be added directly

**Update:** (Just an example to use sub-query)

```
SELECT Customer_Name,
       Customer_Address,
       Customer_Telephone
FROM   CustomerInfo
WHERE  CustomerID in (SELECT CustomerID
                     FROM   CustomerInfo
                     WHERE  CustomerID = 21345432);
```

Comment: But the sub-query is so fancy!

Comment: I'm trying to create a Sub-Query though how would i go about doing that i have been watching YouTube videos can't seem to get my head around it

Comment: @JoshHardy -- see my answer using "specialID"

Comment: @JoshHardy - You need to use sub-query only when it is really needed in your case it is straight forward. Updated my answer with sub-query

Comment: @Hogan - Looks like OP just want to see `sub-query`

Comment: @Prdp sorry still learning SQL it's all new to me haha! what do you mean a join? Between other tables?

Comment: A join happens when mommy table and daddy table love each other very much. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/261/join#t=201701051634364165115